# I upload image on server in circular format and It'll retrive in same formate but with black background.. Ho to remove that background?

Tags: android, bitmap, upload, imageview, geometry

//Look like I again stuck with major problem actually

I want circular imageview and I got that but it convert selected image into circular form not imageview

```
        /*Here is the Code which convert imagefile into circle*/

        // May be I have to convert Imageview in circular form not the image


            public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null) {

                        int column_index = cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    } else
                        return null;
                }

                public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
                    // Decode image size
                    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

                    // The new size we want to scale to
                    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

                    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
                    int scale = 1;
                    while (true) {
                        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                            break;
                        width_tmp /= 2;
                        height_tmp /= 2;
                        scale *= 2;
                    }

                    // Decode with inSampleSize
                    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

                    imageview1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
                    //Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 100);
                    Bitmap conv_bm=getCircularBitmapImage(resized);
                    imageview1.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);
                    //imageview1.setBackground(null);


                    /*RoundedImage = new Roundimage(bitmap);
                    imageview1.setImageDrawable(RoundedImage);*/

                }
```

//This class convert image bitmap into circular format

```
                private Bitmap getCircularBitmapImage(Bitmap resized) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
                    int size = Math.min(resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight());  
                    int x = (resized.getWidth() - size) / 2;  
                    int y = (resized.getHeight() - size) / 2;  
                    Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resized, x, y, size, size);  
                    if (squaredBitmap != resized) {  
                        resized.recycle();  
                    }  
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 

                    Paint paint = new Paint();  
                    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);  
                    paint.setShader(shader);  
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true); 

                    float r = size / 2f;  
                    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);  

                    squaredBitmap.recycle();  


                    return bitmap;  
                }  


        // Here I write code for Image retrive from server

        byte[] res1 = Base64.decode(result.getString("image"),0);
                                InputStream blob=new ByteArrayInputStream(res1);
                                Drawable dUser = Drawable.createFromStream(blob , "image");
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(dUser);

    // This code is retrive blob image from server but with black sourroundings

    // I want to remove that black background[enter image description here][1]

// As display in image That black bacground is not worth in circle display So I just want to remove that

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6KNV.jpg
```

Comment: Isn't it better to keep the image in the original format and use some library like this: [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)? That way your code would be more flexible in case you want to show your images in any other formats.

Comment: Thanks..!! I'll try..!

Comment: Yeah..! its done... You saved me :)

Comment: Now its only one issue that When I upload HD image it retrive with white space at bottom..